# python- how to send file to different network using socket

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

morning sensei, im learning network programming using socket now. i have able to transfer file from my laptop to my smartphone in the some network using public ip. however if im trying to transfer it to other phone in different network it doesnt work and the phone cant connect. 
here is my server.py:

```
import sys
import socket
import os

host = ''
skServer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
skServer.bind((host,2525))
skServer.listen(10)
print ("Server Active")
bFileFound = 0

while True:
    Content,Address = skServer.accept()
    print (Address, "connected")
    FileName = Content.recv(8192)
    sFileName = FileName.decode('utf-8')

    for file in os.listdir("files/"):
        if file == sFileName:
            bFileFound = 1
            break

    if bFileFound == 0:
        print (sFileName+" Not Found On Server")


    else:
        print (sFileName," File Found")
        fUploadFile = open("files/"+sFileName,"rb+")
        sRead = fUploadFile.read(8192)
        while sRead:
            Content.sendall(sRead)
            sRead = fUploadFile.read(8192)
        print ("Sending Completed")


Content.close()
skServer.close()
```

and here is my client.py:

```
import sys
import socket 

skClient = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
skClient.connect(("<ip public>",2525))

sFileName = input("Enter Filename to download from server : ")
sData = "Temp"

while True:
    skClient.sendall(sFileName.encode('utf-8'))
    sData = skClient.recv(8192)
    fDownloadFile = open("storage/emulated/0/qpython"+sFileName,"wb+")
    while sData:
        fDownloadFile.write(sData)
        sData = skClient.recv(8192)
    print ("Download Completed")

skClient.close()
```

is there any way i can use my script globally so any network can access it?

Comment: You might want to dive into the basics of networking. It should be very helpful for network programming. And BTW it is not a suitable topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly.  Some providers restrict certain types of network traffic.

You have several alternatives, one of which is to have a common VPN connection available to both devices.  This technology will encapsulate your program's traffic, so the program should work the way you wish.

Comment: any suggestion for vpn i can use for both phone and computer ? @Rick Lentz

Comment: I don't because it depends on so many factors.  My attempted answer is trying to help you get your client/server program working as you outlined.  Hope this helps!